# Deleting data out of a OpenGL VBO

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I have a VBO that holds 4096 cubes, and I am wondering if I can edit the VBO to actually remove a cube. Here is my code for rendering my vbo (I know I am rendering it in the old fashion):

```
for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++) {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(x, y, z);
                glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }

    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Very simple. Now can I actually use a method to remove data from the vbo? Do I have to create a separate arraylist and add all the cubes to it and remove them from there? I am using LWJGL, I doubt that matters though.

Comment: You are not drawing 4096 cubes. Your buffer object does not hold 4096 cube (or if it does, you're not using most of them). You are drawing the *same cube 4096 times*, using different positions. I see this because you are calling glDrawArrays with the *same parameters*. Thus, you're drawing with the same vertex data.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. How would I draw multiple cubes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if I can edit the VBO to actually remove a cube.

1. `glMapBuffer()` to get a writable pointer.
2. Swap the vertices you want to remove to the end of the VBO.
3. `glUnmapBuffer()` to re-upload the VBO.
4. Make sure to reduce the `count` argument to `glDrawElements()` (or whatever you use) appropriately.

You can also get creative with `glBufferSubData()`.